# MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2059 MQJE011: Socket connection attempt refused

Tags: java, spring, sockets, connection, ibm-mq

We post messages to queue from our Java application. Recently we moved to new high availabulity Production server with same configuration as our old. But now we see a new issue whenever we are trying to post messages. After posting few messages we are getting:

> "MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager An MQException occurred:
>   Completion Code 2, Reason 2059 MQJE011: Socket connection attempt
>   refused"

we did telnet and everything looks fine.The other part is whenever our MQ team tries to enable trace to capture error it works fine.

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager for 'AXMQMTIMSPRDHA:AXMQMTIMSPRDHA_QM'; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2059
MQJE011: Socket connection attempt refused
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:469)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:534)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:641)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:630)
        at com.lowes.trf.rerate.jms.MessageSender.sendMessageAsXml(MessageSender.java:54)
        at com.lowes.trf.rerate.jms.MessageSender$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b52d5402.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
        at com.lowes.trf.rerate.jms.MessageSender$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c88e6908.sendMessageAsXml(<generated>)
        at com.lowes.trf.rerate.service.ReRateService.sendMessageAsXml(ReRateService.java:151)
        at com.lowes.trf.rerate.batch.controller.ReRateBatchController.postResponseToEsbAsXml(ReRateBatchController.java:300)
        at com.lowes.trf.rerate.batch.controller.ReRateBatchController.execute(ReRateBatchController.java:229)
        at com.lowes.trf.rerate.batch.controller.ReRateBatchController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$66bcc521.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:627)
        at com.lowes.trf.rerate.batch.controller.ReRateBatchController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$44b4ed47.execute(<generated>)
        at com.lowes.trf.rerate.batch.controller.ReRateBatchController.main(ReRateBatchController.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager for 'AXMQMTIMSPRDHA:AXMQMTIMSPRDHA_QM'
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.services.ConfigEnvironment.newException(ConfigEnvironment.java:586)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createQM(MQConnection.java:2110)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createQMNonXA(MQConnection.java:1532)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection.<init>(MQQueueConnection.java:150)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:185)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:112)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:1050)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.access$500(JmsTemplate.java:85)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$JmsTemplateResourceFactory.createConnection(JmsTemplate.java:1031)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalSession(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:297)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:453)
        ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0):

[IBM Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041290_.htm) says the remote MQ Manager is possibly down, and make sure the channels you are using are fine. Also when you see the connection being refused, run `dspmq` on the remote machine to ensure the MQManager is really up.